# openstack-install issues

Tags: 14.04, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

openstck-install failed during Landscape deployment with error as below in commands.log.

```
Problem deploying Landscape: {'output': "2014-12-03 14:49:09 [DEBUG] deployer.cli: Using runtime GoEnvironment on maas\n2014-12-03 14:49:09 [INFO] deployer.cli: Starting deployment of landscape-dense-maas\n2014-12-03 14:49:09 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Getting charms...\n2014-12-03 14:49:09 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/ubuntu/.juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_haproxy-1\n2014-12-03 14:49:09 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/haproxy-1\n2014-12-03 14:49:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/ubuntu/.juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_postgresql-3\n2014-12-03 14:49:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/postgresql-3\n2014-12-03 14:49:12 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/ubuntu/.juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_landscape-server\n2014-12-03 14:49:12 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/landscape-server-2\n2014-12-03 14:49:13 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/ubuntu/.juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_apache2-4\n2014-12-03 14:49:13 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/apache2-4\n2014-12-03 14:49:14 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/ubuntu/.juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_rabbitmq-server-7\n2014-12-03 14:49:14 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-7\n2014-12-03 14:49:17 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/ubuntu/.juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_landscape-server\n2014-12-03 14:49:17 [DEBUG] deployer.deploy: Resolving configuration\n2014-12-03 14:49:17 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2014-12-03 14:49:17 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2014-12-03 14:49:17 [INFO] deployer.import: Deploying services...\n2014-12-03 14:49:17 [DEBUG] deployer.import: <deployer.env.go.GoEnvironment object at 0x7f6bf4d8df10>\n2014-12-03 14:49:18 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service apache2 using cs:trusty/apache2-4\n2014-12-03 14:49:18 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Refetching status for placement deploys\n2014-12-03 14:49:35 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service haproxy using cs:trusty/haproxy-1\n2014-12-03 14:49:40 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service landscape using cs:trusty/landscape-server\n2014-12-03 14:49:47 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service landscape-msg using cs:trusty/landscape-server\n2014-12-03 14:49:52 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service postgresql using cs:trusty/postgresql-3\n2014-12-03 14:50:17 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service rabbitmq-server using cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-7\n2014-12-03 14:50:33 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Adding units...\n2014-12-03 14:50:33 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'apache2' does not need any more units added.\n2014-12-03 14:50:33 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'haproxy' does not need any more units added.\n2014-12-03 14:50:33 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'landscape' does not need any more units added.\n2014-12-03 14:50:33 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'landscape-msg' does not need any more units added.\n2014-12-03 14:50:33 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'postgresql' does not need any more units added.\n2014-12-03 14:50:33 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'rabbitmq-server' does not need any more units added.\n2014-12-03 14:50:33 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Waiting for units before adding relations\n2014-12-03 15:29:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/0 change:pending\n2014-12-03 15:30:15 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/1 change:pending\n2014-12-03 15:31:44 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/2 change:pending\n2014-12-03 15:33:03 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:pending\n2014-12-03 15:35:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/4 change:pending\n2014-12-03 15:37:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/5 change:pending\n2014-12-03 16:21:02 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2014-12-03 16:21:02 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2014-12-03 16:21:02 [ERROR] deployer.import: Reached deployment timeout.. exiting\n2014-12-03 16:21:02 [INFO] deployer.cli: Deployment stopped. run time: 5513.43\n", 'status': 1}
DEBUG • 12-03 16:21:02 [LINE:51, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils • Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 66, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 175, in do_install
    self.display_controller).run()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 699, in run
    self.deploy_landscape()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 731, in deploy_landscape
    raise Exception("Error deploying Landscape.")
Exception: Error deploying Landscape.
```

Also is there way to resume from the point where it failed and where the step by step logs available for openstack-install process, as commands.log doesnt give the clear logs.

Comment: What was the command that caused it to fail?

Comment: openstack-install

Comment: looks like it is timing out attempting to connect to your MAAS machine. Was that setup prior to running the installer?

Comment: Hi Netra, you hit a time out deploying the landscape charm bundle which could be a number of things.  At the command line can you run `juju status` and paste the result?  If that works we will probably need more information to chase down what is wrong but that is a start.

Answer (score 2):

I need more information to help you triage the failure, please edit your question and we will get it sorted.

As for your second question: there is no way to resume the installer, no.

If you would like this feature, can you please file an issue?  (Even having the fields remain filled in would be a help!)

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer

Thanks!

Comment: FYI we've landed code that support preseeded configuration options.